# Pass data to other components in React-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I have the following routes for Login and Home component:

```
<Route exact path="/" name="Login Page" component={Login} />
<Route path="/home" name="Home" component={Home} />
```

The Login component uses react-final-form to submit user's input to the back-end and then go to Home like this

```
onSave = async (values) => {

 const user = await Api.postURL("/register", values);
 window.location.href = '/home';
}
```

How would I pass user's data from the back-end to Home component to later display it?

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: You can use `redux` or `context`

Comment: shouldn't you be using `history.push("/")` to prevent a browser refresh? otherwise you have to save the data in local storage or something. As Tien said you could easily save the user object using the context api and load it into your home screen.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
onSave = async (values) => {
   const user = await Api.postURL("/register", values);
   localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(user));
   window.location.href = '/home';
}
```

And in your `Home` component,

```
class Home extends React.Component{
  render(){
     const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
     return(
        ...
     );
  }
}
```

---

Another way is using [`Redirect`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) from `react-router-dom` package.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'


onSave = async (values) => {
   const user = await Api.postURL("/register", values);
   <Redirect to={{
         pathname: '/home',
         state: { user:  JSON.stringify(user)}
     }}
   />
}
```

And in your `Home` component,

```
class Home extends React.Component{
  render(){
     const user = JSON.parse(this.props.location.state.user);
     return(
        ...
     );
  }
}
```